# Why don't my edges bevel in the same direction?

Tags: modeling, objects, edges, bevel, loop

I am working on a project to create a bed frame like the one pictured below. I figured the best way to do so would be some beveling.

[image: Bed frame I took inspiration from]

I was having trouble on the original object. I decided to show my example on a new cube to get my point across.

I added loop cuts similar to the bedframe I am working on.

I extruded my loops cuts to the desired size.

When I threw on the first bevel I got the results I wanted, but when i threw on the second bevel I did not.

I want all of my bevels to match the first one.

[image: Final results of my failed attempt]

Here is the link for my test file so you can see what I did.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't link to Google Drive. it is telling me that access is denied, and when people are unnecessarily inconvenienced, they are less likely to want to help. Instead, share your actual blend file (and not a video) here. https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=JAJXPglD" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/JAJXPglD/)

Comment: @R-800 Do you have any idea though on how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. I've been away for a while. I wasn't able to reproduce your issue. But I did notice that your face normals are not all facing the same way, which can cause all sorts of issues. I wasn't able to get your strange, inverted bevel behavior to happen even with flipped normals when I tested this, though. So this may not be your issue. Still, your normals need to all be facing the same way.

Comment: @R-800 Hey thanks for the response. Yeah I fixed my normals and still had the issue, but was able to resolve said issue by using insets instead of the extrude method I was using. Cheers!